# transpiled code (babel) seems not working in Browser

Tags: angularjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

Hi I'm working on an existing app which needs enhancements. The app is built using angularJS, Babel, webpack. I struggled running the app locally and finally succeeded in running it after making changes to how we call a basedirective (like below) which was using babel next generation javascript notation to regular notation (a compiler is present on babel site to do this).

```
function filtersDirective() {
return {
 ...baseDirective(template, FiltersCtrl),
 ...{
  bindToController: {
     customers: '=',
     regions: '=',
     managers: '=',
     projects: '=',
     statuses: '=',
    },
  },
 }
}
```

Now the issue is I'm able to run this app locally and also able to build the bundle files (app.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js, manifest.bundle.js) but when I deploy these files to my test server, the console error is like below.

```
ReferenceError: production is not defined
at dispatchXhrRequest (vendor.bundle.js:24340)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at xhrAdapter (vendor.bundle.js:24325)
at dispatchRequest (vendor.bundle.js:92054)
at <anonymous>
vendor.bundle.js:65932 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
at https://@domain/cdn/3.2.1/vendor.bundle.js:5202:31
at https://@domain/cdn/3.2.1/vendor.bundle.js:5090:28
at f1 (https://@domain/cdn/3.2.1/vendor.bundle.js:5070:27)
at https://@domain/cdn/3.2.1/vendor.bundle.js:4920:35
at https://@domain/cdn/3.2.1/vendor.bundle.js:4920:35
at https://@domain/cdn/3.2.1/vendor.bundle.js:4920:35
at https://@domain/cdn/3.2.1/vendor.bundle.js:4672:27
at getAttributeFromProjects (https://@domain/cdn/3.2.1/app.bundle.js:117:10)
at MainController (https://@domain/cdn/3.2.1/app.bundle.js:127:21)
at invoke (https://@domain/cdn/3.2.1/vendor.bundle.js:58052:17) <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

My Traspiled app.bundle.js looks like below

```
webpackJsonp([1], {

        /***/
        101:
            /***/
            (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

                "use strict";
                /* harmony import */
                var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_deepmerge__ = __webpack_require__(69);
                /* harmony import */
                var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_deepmerge___default = __webpack_require__.n(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_deepmerge__);


                const baseConfig = {
                    title: 'Test Dashboard',
                    dashboard: {
                        title: 'Test Report',
                        subtitle: 'Weekly Highlights'
                    },
                    header: {
                        title: 'Company Confidential',
                        nav: 'Test'
                    }
                }

                let config = baseConfig
                if (window.AppConfig) {
                    if (window.AppConfig.config) {
                        config = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_deepmerge___default.a(baseConfig, window.AppConfig.config)
                    }
                }

                const {
                    title,
                    dashboard,
                    header,
                    statusBar
                } = config
                /* harmony export (immutable) */
                __webpack_exports__["c"] = title;

                /* harmony export (immutable) */
                __webpack_exports__["a"] = dashboard;

                /* unused harmony export header */

                /* unused harmony export statusBar */


                /* harmony default export */
                __webpack_exports__["b"] = (config);


                /***/
            }),

        /***/
        222:
            /***/
            (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

                    "use strict";
                    /* harmony export (binding) */
                    __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "b", function() {
                        return resolve;
                    });
                    /* harmony import */
                    var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_ramda__ = __webpack_require__(36);
                    /* harmony import */
                    var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_ramda___default = __webpack_require__.n(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_ramda__);
                    /* harmony import */
                    var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_angular__ = __webpack_require__(7);
                    /* harmony import */
                    var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_angular___default = __webpack_require__.n(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_angular__);
                    /* harmony import */
                    var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__utils__ = __webpack_require__(4);
                    /* harmony import */
                    var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__services_api__ = __webpack_require__(99);
                    /* harmony import */
                    var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__appConfig_config__ = __webpack_require__(101);
                    /* harmony import */
                    var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__dashboard_html__ = __webpack_require__(479);
                    /* harmony import */
                    var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__dashboard_html___default = __webpack_require__.n(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__dashboard_html__);
                    /* harmony reexport (default from non-hamory) */
                    __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "c", function() {
                        return __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__dashboard_html___default.a;
                    });
```

Which is very different from previous version of app.bundle.js which is on prod server which looks like below

```
webpackJsonp([1], {

        /***/
        10:
            /***/
            (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

                    "use strict";


                    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
                        value: true
                    });
                    exports.getWebpartData = undefined;

                    var _keys = __webpack_require__(124);

                    var _keys2 = _interopRequireDefault(_keys);

                    var _deepmerge = __webpack_require__(76);

                    var _deepmerge2 = _interopRequireDefault(_deepmerge);

                    var _utils = __webpack_require__(4);

                    var _majorMilestones = __webpack_require__(501);

                    var _majorMilestones2 = _interopRequireDefault(_majorMilestones);

                    var _budget = __webpack_require__(502);

                    var _budget2 = _interopRequireDefault(_budget);

                    var _projectRisksAndIssues = __webpack_require__(503);

                    var _projectRisksAndIssues2 = _interopRequireDefault(_projectRisksAndIssues);

                    var _actionItems = __webpack_require__(504);

                    var _actionItems2 = _interopRequireDefault(_actionItems);

                    var _keyDates = __webpack_require__(505);

                    var _keyDates2 = _interopRequireDefault(_keyDates);

                    var _gantt = __webpack_require__(506);

                    var _gantt2 = _interopRequireDefault(_gantt);

                    var _statusBar = __webpack_require__(507);

                    var _statusBar2 = _interopRequireDefault(_statusBar);

                    var _angular = __webpack_require__(6);

                    var _angular2 = _interopRequireDefault(_angular);

                    function _interopRequireDefault(obj) {
                        return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : {
                            default: obj
                        };
                    }
```

below is my package.json file for reference

```
{
"name": "pmrdashboard",
"version": "3.2.1",
"dependencies": {
    "@cgross/angular-notify": "2.5.1",
    "angular": "1.4.2",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.12.2",
    "angular-chart.js": "^1.0.1",
    "angular-gantt": "^1.2.13",
    "angular-google-chart": "^0.1.0",
    "angular-messages": "~1.4.2",
    "angular-moment": "1.0.1",
    "angular-pubsub": "^0.2.0",
    "angular-resource": "~1.4.2",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.4.2",
    "angular-strap": "^2.3.9",
    "angular-toastr": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "animate.css": "~3.4.0",
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "2.1.0",
    "deepmerge": "^1.3.2",
    "echo-loader": "0.0.1",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "moment": "2.10.6",
    "ngsticky-puemos": "^0.0.4",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "ramda": "^0.22.1"
},
"scripts": {
    "dev": "babel-node scripts/cli.js dev",
    "serve": "babel-node scripts/cli.js serve",
    "build": "babel-node scripts/cli.js build --upload=false --plugins dynamic-import-node",
    "deploy": "babel-node scripts/cli.js build",
    "serve:prod": "babel-node scripts/cli.js serve:prod",
    "serve:optimize": "babel-node scripts/cli.js serve:prod --optimize=true",
    "serve:cdn": "babel-node scripts/cli.js serve:prod --usecdn=true"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-angularjs-annotate": "^0.7.0",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-external-helpers": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.1",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "0.1.16",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.1",
    "eslint": "2.13.1",
    "eslint-config-angular": "^0.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "^2.4.0",
    "execa": "^0.6.3",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.1",
    "fs-extra": "^3.0.1",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "html-webpack-harddisk-plugin": "0.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.28.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "*",
    "http-server": "^0.10.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "3.3.1",
    "imports-loader": "0.7.1",
    "jshint-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "2.0.2",
    "rollup": "^0.43.0",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^2.7.1",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.5",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.7",
    "ssh-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.7",
    "style-loader": "0.17.0",
    "svg-loader": "0.0.2",
    "url-loader": "0.5.8",
    "webpack": "3.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.0",
    "yargs": "^8.0.1"
},
"engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
}
}
```

webpack config files: it's a folder with .babelrc, dev.js, server.js, prod.js, share.js and below is share.js file

```
const path = require('path')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin = require('html-webpack-harddisk-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const {
   rm
} = require('shelljs')
const pkg = require('../package.json')
const webpack = require('webpack')

const baseChunks = ['config', 'app']

const basePlugins = (chunks, enableHtml) => {
const html = enableHtml ?
    [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'PMR Client',
            filename: './index.html',
            template: './src/client/index.ejs',
            chunksSortMode: (a, b) => chunks.indexOf(a.names[0]) - chunks.indexOf(b.names[0]),
            alwaysWriteToDisk: true,
            env: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackHarddiskPlugin(),
    ] :
    []
return [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
    ...html,
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
]
}

const baseEntries = {
app: './src/app/index.js',
config: `./clients/${process.env.CLIENT}/config.js`,
}

const baseOutput = () => {
const output = {
    path: path.join(__dirname, `../dist/cdn/${pkg.version}`),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
}
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && process.env.UPLOAD === 'true') {
    output['publicPath'] = `//streamlinedoffice.com/pmr/cdn/${pkg.version}/`
}
return output
}

const sourceMap = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') ? '' : 'sourceMap'

const getBaseConfig = ({
plugins = [],
chunks = [],
entries = baseEntries,
enableHtml = false
} = {}) => {
rm('-rf', path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'))

const ch = [...baseChunks, ...chunks]
return {
    entry: entries,
    output: baseOutput(),
    target: 'web',
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    plugins: [...basePlugins(ch, enableHtml), ...plugins],
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options: {
                        minimize: true,
                        root: '../src/assets/images',
                    },
                }, ],
            },
            {
                test: [/src\/app.*\.js$/, /client.*\.js$/],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    // loader:'echo-loader',
                },
            },
            {
                test: [/\.css$/, /\.scss$/],
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader', `sass-loader?${sourceMap}`],
                }),
            },
            {
                test: /bootstrap-sass\/assets\/javascripts\//,
                use: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery'
            },
            // Font Definitions
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=65000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]',
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]',
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff2$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]',
            },
            {
                test: /\.[ot]tf$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=65000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]',
            },
            {
                test: /\.eot$/,
                loader: 'url-loader?limit=65000&mimetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]',
            },
            {
                test: /\.png$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192',
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                    'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&publicPath=../&name=./img/[hash].[ext]',
                    {
                        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                        query: {
                            gifsicle: {
                                interlaced: false,
                            },
                            progressive: true,
                            optipng: {
                                optimizationLevel: 7,
                            },
                            bypassOnDebug: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
}
}
module.exports = getBaseConfig
```

Below is the script used to build the app.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js an d manifest.bundle.js files (this file is on scripts/cmds/prod.js)

```
import {
echo,
head,
execStrict,
ls,
copy,
rmdir,
mkdir
} from '../utils'
import fs from 'fs-extra'
import path from 'path'
import {
rollup
} from 'rollup'
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'

const compiler = client =>
rollup({
    entry: `./clients/${client}/config.js`,
    plugins: [
        resolve(),
        babel({
            exclude: 'node_modules/**',
            babelrc: false,
            presets: [
                ['env',
                    {
                        modules: false,
                        targets: {
                            browsers: [
                                "last 3 versions",
                                "Explorer 9",
                            ],
                        },
                    },
                ],
            ],
            plugins: ['external-helpers'],
            externalHelpers: true
        }),
    ],
}).then(bundle =>
    bundle.write({
        format: 'cjs',
        dest: path.join(__dirname, `../../.tmpClients/${client}/config.js`),
    })
)

const getClients = () =>
fs
.readdirSync('./clients')
.filter(file => fs.lstatSync(path.join('./clients', file)).isDirectory())

const handleCommand = async ({
upload = true,
optimize = true
}) => {
echo(head('Building clients...'))
const clients = getClients()
mkdir('./.tmpClients')

const promises = clients.map(client => {
    compiler(client)
})

await Promise.all(promises)

echo(head('Run production build'))

await execStrict(
    `cross-env UPLOAD=${upload} OPTIMIZE=${optimize} NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/prod.js --progress --colors --define process.env.NODE_ENV="'production'"`
)

echo(head('Copying config files to clients'))
ls('./.tmpClients').forEach(client => {
    copy({
        origin: `./.tmpClients/${client}/*.js`,
        dest: `./dist/clients/${client}`,
    })

    copy({
        origin: `./dist/clients/${client}/index.html`,
        dest: `./dist/clients/${client}/default.aspx`,
    })

    copy({
        origin: './src/client/favicon.ico',
        dest: `./dist/clients/${client}/`,
    })
})
rmdir('./.tmpClients')


}

exports.command = 'build'
exports.describe = 'Create a production build'
exports.handler = handleCommand
exports.builder = {
upload: {
    describe: 'Upload the production files to the cdn',
    type: 'boolean',
    default: true,
},
optimize: {
    describe: 'Toggle the production optimizations, useful to check the production build as development',
    type: 'boolean',
    default: true,
},
}
```

below is .babelrc in webpack folder:

```
{
      "presets": ["env"],
      "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread", "dynamic-import-node"]
}
```

below .babelrc is in global same level as webpack folder

```
{
  "presets":  [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 3 versions","Explorer 9"]
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime", "transform-object-rest-spread", 
["angularjs-annotate", {
    "explicitOnly": true
  }]]
}
```

if anyone ran into such similar issue are know how to resolve it do share your inputs. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Would you mind adding your webpack config file?

Comment: @Ben Hi I added the webpack config files and .babelrc files and also script file used to build the app.